# Can we set privacy for "last seen" status?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, privacy

When I go to any profiles it shows me the last online status for that profile under `visits > seen`.

> seen **X** mins ago

However, I sometimes don't want to let everyone knows that I've visited the site a while ago.
Can we just turn this setting off so that no one will be able to know if I'm online or not?

Comment: Why do you mind? And if you do, the surest way is to logout, or perhaps to switch to po^k^k a private tab, anyways.

Comment: Why is it duplicate? The marked question doesn't have the answer of **my question**.

Comment: Because of the last line - "At a minimum I'd expect it to keep track using dates, not exact times. **But it should be removed altogether**" (my emphasis).

Comment: @ChrisF Well, I was asking if we can **turn on/off** this feature, not just remove it entirely. Someone might find this helpful, and someone might think it's useless. And those answers doesn't satisfy what I really wanted to know.

Comment: The question is a duplicate though. The fact that it doesn't have a satisfactory answer doesn't change that fact.

Comment: I agree it is a duplicate. And I disagree that it is a useful feature. That is what 'birthday party' mode in Chrome et al is for. Whereas last visited timestamps are a useful feature for Stack Exchange sites - if someone posts a question / answer that needs clarification and I comment on it, I want to know if that user has returned to the site since I left that comment (It's useful to know if I'm being ignored, or just not yet being noticed).

Comment: To amplify what @JonW said: I use that info to decide about further action to take on a post with problems that were commented on (DV, flag, vote to delete).  If somebody has been back and has had time to address the problems, but didn't, that's different from the case where he hasn't seen the feedback yet.